# Connecting to a specific Server Ip with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, cordova

I have to build a crossplatform web app for mobile devices, so I'm developing it with html, css and js (then it will pass through phonegap or cordova).

My problem is working with socket.io, and my questions are:

1) Can I connect to a specific ip on the client-side?

Instead on having this:

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

I need this, but this doesn't work:

```
<script src="my-app/folder/js/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://my.server.ip:port');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

2) On the server side, how can I create a server that listen to connections and messages on its IP?

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80, my.server.ip);
```

In this way, the application's users will connect to my server Ip in which I host the chat service.

I suppose that I'm not in thinking in the right logic of socket.io .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will not be connecting to localhost when you deploy the application and the devices will be connecting to the server hostname or IP address.

The following code on your server will run socket.io on an IP address associated with the server on the specified port provided that the server is accessible on that IP address

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(port, ipAddress);
var socket = io.listen(server);
```

The following code should work fine on the client side

```
var socket = new io.Socket();
socket.connect('http://' + ipAddress + ':' + port);
```

Make sure you are able to connect to the IP address across the network from the client device for this to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. My problem right now is that the client side can't load the socket.io lib. I have started a server on 1.2.3.4:1234 and when I connect to this address (my index.html is hosted on Xammp htdocs folder) the console shows me this error "GET http://1.2.3.4:1234/socket.io/socket.io.js ". Why?

Comment: What Express version are you using?

The API has changed from Express 2.x to 3.x, so the answer is in the Socket.IO compatibility section at the Migrating from 2.x to 3.x wiki:

Socket.IO's .listen() method takes an http.Server instance as an argument.
As of 3.x, the return value of express() is not an http.Server instance. To get Socket.IO working with Express 3.x, make sure you manually create and pass your http.Server instance to Socket.IO's .listen() method.