# Socket.io without localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I would like to use Socket.io without localhost on port 8081.
Could it be possible to set an IP address instead of localhost and get the app work? I would like to test it not on localhost but on an IP address. I am kind of new to Socket.io so please provide detailed guide if possible. :-)
I wrote the backend in Node Express, but I can only connect Socket.io using localhost. I can provide some more details if needed.

Socket.io server address: http://185.13.90.140:8081/

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!
J.

Comment: You should always start by [reading the documentation!](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#io-url-options)

Comment: Also, if the usage of [tag:reactjs] is relevant to your question, please [edit] your question to explain why it's relevant. Connecting to a socket.io server on a different IP address has nothing to do with React.

Comment: You might start by providing the definition for `openSocket()` by _[edit]ing your question_. That's not a standard function in socket.io or the React framework.

Comment: Because as your question is written, it is unclear what your goal is. Yes, you want to connect to that IP address, but _why_? Is it just a different address to the same server you're already running on localhost? Or is it running a standalone socket server that you want to run independently of your express server? I'm asking you to [edit] your question and provide more information and so far all you've done is tell me what you can't do without any reasonable explanation as to _why_.

Comment: I am New to Socket.io and I have to use this url (Socket.io server address) http://185.13.90.140:8081/. Every tutorial is about localhost that is why I am confused a bit. I am looking for someone who is a professional at Socket.io. All that I can say right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to a specific Server Ip with Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915149/connecting-to-a-specific-server-ip-with-socket-io)

Comment: Please don't say "I can provide some more details if needed" in the question if you then refuse to give any more details in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `server IP Address` while creating `io` instance,

```
var socket = io("http://185.13.90.140:8081/");
```

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps 127.0.0.1 which is the IP equivalent to localhost?