# How connect a client to a distant node.js server with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I get the client-side on a host. And I launch the server on my computer.
I can connect the client and server when I use the localhost but I can't when I try to connect the client to the specific IP of my computer.

This is how I proceed  :

server side :

```
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(port, 'localhost');
const io = socket(server);
```

client side :

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

(this helped me: [Connecting to a specific Server Ip with Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915149/connecting-to-a-specific-server-ip-with-socket-io))

When I replace localhost by ip I have this issue on my server side :

```
events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 123.123.123.123:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1289:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1354:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1493:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1333:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '123.123.123.123',
  port: 3000
}
```

Why it said address not available? ( it's not really `123.123.132.123` of course )

I don't understand how I can proceed to connect the client from any computer to the server launched on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

In the following line you're saying to you server to listen on `localhost`:

```
server.listen(port, 'localhost');
```

Remove `locahost` if you want to listen from the unspecified address (0.0.0.0 for IPv4) or set your desired IP.

```
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how the client from a computer far away can connect to my server ? I try this `const socket = io.connect('http://123.123.123.123:3000'); ` but that don't work

Comment: If you removed the limitation to only connecting from `localhost`, then you'll have to check if the 3000 port is open to the outside: is this port open in your router, LAN or whatever? do you have any firewall rule blocking connections from the outside?